# A recursive sample splitting scheme (with grid searching)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a data panel, there are several samples in each cross-section, for example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = ["2018-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2021-01-01", "2022-01-01"] * 2
dates.sort()
samples = [1, 2] * 5
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "dates": dates,
        "samples": samples
    }
)
```

I want to create a cross-validation generator, in which I do validation for 3 times:

1. The first time, samples in `["2018-01-01", "2019-01-01"]` are the training samples, and in `["2020-01-01"]` are the validation samples;
2. The second time, samples in `["2018-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2020-01-01"]` are the training samples, and in `["2021-01-01"]` are the validation samples;
3. The last time, samples in `["2018-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2021-01-01"]` are the training samples, and in `["2022-01-01"]` are the validation samples.

Briefly, the training set recursively increases while the validation set keeps a constant length.

I had thought about `PredefinedSplit()` function from `sklearn.model_selection`, but the problems are:

1. As you see, I didn't include all samples (either in the testing set or the validation set) each time;
2. `["2020-01-01"]` is in training set in the first and second time but not the first time validation.

This makes `PredefinedSplit()` powerless.

**My question is**: how to customise this splitting scheme? It is better to keep it in `sklearn` as I want to pass this splitting scheme into `GridSearchCV()` for grid searching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially the purpose of `TimeSeriesSplit` ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html)).

---

But if you want more control, the `cv` parameter of grid search and friends accepts

> An iterable yielding (train, test) splits as arrays of indices.

so a list of pairs of lists of integers should work, e.g.

```
cv = [
    ([0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5]),
    ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7]),
    ...
]
```

(which you should be able to clean up with generator expressions and `range`, for larger examples).